# How differentiability and Intermediate Value Property(IVP) are related?

Tags: real-analysis

We know that a function which is continuous on intreval $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ then it has certainly has IVP. But how can we guarantee that if a function $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b) $ then $f'$ has IVP?

if $f$ is diffentiable then $f$ must be continuous but this doesn't tell anything about the the continuity or monotonicity of $f'$. So how these two concepts are related to each other? HELP PLEASE. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The proof is different than for continuous case.

Take $x_1<x_2$ and assume $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ (the other case is solved similarly)

Take $y$ with $f(x_1)<y<f(x_2)$ and you need to prove that there is $x$ with $x_1<x<x_2$ with $f(x)=y$, which is equivalent with $f(x)-y=0$. The sketch of the proof works as follows:

1. Take the antiderivative of $f(t)-y$, which is $h(t)=f(t)-yt$
2. $h$ is continuous on $[x_1,x_2]$ so it has a min and a max
3. $h'(x_1)<0$ and $h'(x_2)>0$
4. $h'(x_1)<0$ implies that the min of $h$ is not attained in $x_1$
5. $h'(x_2)>0$ implies that the min of $h$ is not attained in $x_2$

So the min of $h$ is attained somewhere in $x \in (x_1,x_2)$. Now apply Fermat's theorem to obtain $h'(x)=f(x)-y=0$

You may also take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis)) for the proof.